# Changing the H1 with for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, innerhtml

JS newbie here. I am trying to get all the values in an H1 tag and change the ones have lower than 4 lengths.

It says "Please Answer the Questions" I need it to say "Please answer Hello Questions"

```js
let header = document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML;
let splittedText = header.split(" ");

function seperateText() {
  for (let i = 0; i < splittedText.length; i++) {
    if (splittedText[i].length < 4) {

      splittedText[i].innerHTML = "Hello"
    }
  }
  // console.log(splittedText[i]);
  return splittedText[i].innerHTML;
}
seperateText();
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Please Answer the Questions</h1>
```

Comment: Strings don’t have an `innerHTML` property. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Find out what `splittedText` is. Find out what `splittedText[i]` is. It’s _not_ an element. Why do you return `splittedText[i].innerHTML` outside of the loop? This expression is meaningless. Arrays have a `join` method.

Comment: Your snippet gives relevant console errors. Fix them

Comment: You're splitting a string, which gives you an array of strings. Next you iterate over those strings, and trying to set their `.innerHTML`, which they don't have. You need to call `.map()` on your array to change individual words, then set the joined result as `header.innerHTML`: https://jsfiddle.net/e09fs4aq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying the set innerHTML of a string - that does not work

Also the [i] does not exist outside the loop

Try this map

```js
const seperateText = str => {
  let splittedText = str.split(" ");
  return splittedText.map(word => word.length > 4 ? word : "hello").join(" ");
}

let header1 = document.getElementById("h1")
header1.innerHTML = seperateText(header1.innerHTML);

let header2 = document.getElementById("empty")
header2.innerHTML = seperateText(header2.innerHTML);
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Please Answer the Questions</h1>
<h1 id="empty"></h1>
```

or this replace

```js
const seperateText = str => {
  return str.replace(/\b(\w+)\b/gi, match => match.length < 4 ? "hello" : match);
}

let header1 = document.getElementById("h1")
header1.innerHTML = seperateText(header1.innerHTML);

let header2 = document.getElementById("empty")
header2.innerHTML = seperateText(header2.innerHTML);
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Please Answer the Questions</h1>
<h1 id="empty"></h1>
```